# Webpack file-loader : rewrite the path

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

How to change the output directory of file copied with file-loader ?

**Configuration :**

```
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
...
loaders : [
{
  test : /\.html$/,
  include : SRC_DIR + "/main/html",
  loader : 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]'
},
```

- If I use [path], output = full source directory.
- If I don't, output=files are on root output directory

How to keep only a part of the initial path ?

**Example :**

```
 source : /src/main/html/app/sample.html
 output : /dist/app/sample.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (I haven't tested it)

```
plugins: [
     ...
     new CopyWebpackPlugin([
       { from: SRC_DIR + "/main/html" }
     ]),
     ...
  ]
```

Comment: I changed a little thing in your answer, it works now